# Windows Service - ODBC - Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, windows-services, odbc

I have a legacy Windows Service that basically prints Crystal Reports.

The service runs under a specific administrator account, if i run it under a different administrator level account it actually prints nothing! (that is an administrator account that is not logged into the machine), but doesn't error as it can still connect to the database.

Crystal Reports uses an ODBC System DSN (SQL Native Client 10.0 with no SPN specified) with Integrated Windows Authentication to log into SQL Server.

The question is if the machine restarts and the Windows Service is set to start on system start will the ODBC login still work?

P.S. The service is hosted on a Windows 7 machine that is part of the all encompassing domain.

Google in this case is not my friend, and documentation on Integrated Windows Authentication is very scarce and very unhelpful.

Comment: how does the windows service configured? Is it configured to run for specific account or any account that logs in to the computer

Comment: As long as the service is set to run under the correct account and to start automatically, then yes, it should. Seems easy enough to test - just reboot the machine and see what happens. Look out for the password expiring on the service's account though.